# shiny navbarpage title href color change from blue to white

Tags: fonts, colors, shiny, title

How do i change the href'ed navbarpage title default color - in this case the stackoverflow is blue in color.  How can I change it to white.

```
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(inverse = TRUE,
    title=HTML("<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow</a>"),
    tabPanel("tab1")
    ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
))
```

I figured I need to change the `body link` attribute and when I altered the code as follows:

```
tags$html(<body link="white">
<p><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a></p>
</body>)
```

I am getting errors as follows:

```
Error: unexpected '<' in "<"
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
```

I checked the code, for every opening `<` there is a closing `/>` in html and for every `(` there is a closing `)`.

How do I change the color of the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage(inverse = TRUE,
    title=HTML("<a style=color:white;  href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow</a>"),
    tabPanel("tab1")
    ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
))
```